# how to convert from std::vector to args

Tags: c++, vector, variadic-functions

I have a function which takes multiple arguments like this:

```
void test(const auto&...args)
{
   typedef boost::variant<int, float, std::string> Variant;
   std::vector<Variant> vec = {args...}
}
```

this works fine - arguments are inside the vector as different types according to the Variant

I would like to fetch arguments from a similar vector and put it back into a function that takes args...

something like this :

```
args = vec;
test2(args);

void test2(const auto&...args);
```

how can this be done?

Comment: Might I ask why you need this? Writing a function over the vector itself being a parameter is more preferable in about any case. Since newer versions of C++ can instantiate vectors like vector a = {1,2,3}, there is not much usage for multiple arguments anyway. Can be that in your case it makes sense, but before we deal with an XY-problem here...

Comment: @Aziuth, Im trying to work around the implicit error issue with using lambda functions added to a queue via a base class with virtual pure function definition - parameterless lambdas is no issue is getting those parameters across thats the problem - so far I have managed to transfer known types but not multiple like args...

Comment: so far I have solved it using a fixed type to transfer [std::vector<Variant>] I then on the receiving end handle the vectors elements as if they were normal args - this however will make test2 definition unflexible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible. Parameter packs must be determined at compile time, in order to be expanded. Each uniquely-typed parameter pack becomes its own unique function call, created at compile time.

Obviously, the size of a vector is not known until run time. C++ does not work like that, fundamentally.

Comment: I was hoping for something like boost::bind to help with this issue

Comment: @serup: i think the fundamental problem is that in your first example, everything is known at compile time, but what you want to do is only known at runtime (as Sam says, the vector can contain any number of items at that point) and that is why it cannot be done.

Comment: how would you then use a function / lambda which has the definition [](const auto&...args) { }   -- from a runtime allocated and executed function - so far I have not found a solution, except to change the `const auto&...args` to `std::vector<Variant>` and then have the receiving function handle the vector elements as if they are normal args

Comment: As I explained in my answer: you can't. C++ does not work this way. The C++ language's fundamental design makes this logically impossible.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to do this. But since the size of a vector is only known at runtime, errors from mismatched sizes must occur at runtime too.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
template<std::size_t... S>
void unpack_vector(const std::vector<Variant>& vec, std::index_sequence<S...>) {
    test2(vec[S]...);
}

template<std::size_t size>
void unpack_vector(const std::vector<Variant>& vec) {
    if (vec.size() != size) throw /* choose your error */;
    unpack_vector(vec, std::make_index_sequence<size>());
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
unpack_vector<6>(vec);
```

Note that this function will send `Variant` instances to the function `test2`.

I must admit this might be a bad idea, runtime errors are not there best. I suggest you to review your design in order to not need this.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I agree not the way to go - I decided to make my receving functions more adapt to handling the received Variants - something like this :
`auto fnTest = [](std::vector<Variant> vec) { 
std::cout << "parameters : ";
for(auto a: vec) { std::cout << a << ","; } std::cout << std::endl;
};`

so obviously each function must know types of arguments in order to fetch them like this `int param = boost::get<int>(a);`

Comment: @serup instead of a vector of variant, if you can, use a tuple. tuples can be expanded into Args and they are much faster. Of course, that may mean to change your destiny, but it worth it.

Comment: Yes worth looking into - however so far the boost variant ways of getting value is so easy, with tuples I am not sure It would be so easy to read - performance vs. readability, but still perhaps

Answer (score 2):

based on @Guillaume Racicot answer, I then found this solution (snippet from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) :

This example shows how a std::tuple can be converted into arguments for a function invocation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<typename Func, typename Tup, std::size_t... index>
decltype(auto) invoke_helper(Func&& func, Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<index...>)
{
    return func(std::get<index>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))...);
}

template<typename Func, typename Tup>
decltype(auto) invoke(Func&& func, Tup&& tup)
{
    constexpr auto Size = std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tup>::type>::value;
    return invoke_helper(std::forward<Func>(func),
                         std::forward<Tup>(tup),
                         std::make_index_sequence<Size>{});
}

void foo(int a, const std::string& b, float c)
{
    std::cout << a << " , " << b << " , " << c << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto args = std::make_tuple(2, "Hello", 3.5);
    invoke(foo, args);
}
```

Output:

2 , Hello , 3.5

Comment: however this example have compile time make_tuple creating the args, so this would also not be usable, however it comes close to a viable solution